# LogoutSuccessHandler unit case not working

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-security

Integration test for `LogoutSuccessHandler` is not working.

I have implemented LogoutSuccessHandler as CustomLogOutHandler in my spring security application. While running application everything is working fine this custom log out handler is getting called when I am logging off from application.

But while writing unit test case for it, I am not able to invoke this CustomLogOutHandler and flow is going to other filters written in the application.

Code snippet looks like:

```
public class CustomLogOutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
  private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomLogOutHandler.class);
  @Autowired
  private SessionContextRepository redisContextRepository;

 @Autowired
  private SessionService sessionService;

  @Value("X-Auth-Token")
  private String tokenHeader;

  @Override
  public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (httpServletRequest != null) {
      .....
    }
```

Configuration looks like :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/errors/portal/*",
                    "/error**"
            ) //internal login
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(getCustomLogOutHandler())
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
```

My Test class looks like:

```
RedisSessionContext context = Mockito.mock(RedisSessionContext.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(rediscontext).deleteSessionContext(Mockito.anyString());

Mockito.when(rediscontext.getSessionContext(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(context);
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/logout").header("userName", "00001011181")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andReturn();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Token is null", result.getResponse().getHeader("authToken"));
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: format your code please

Comment: Show your Spring Security Test Configuration. @ContextConfiguration

Comment: Full test would be nice to have. It seems that you dont have authenticated user to logout. Perhaps worth trying something like RunAsUserToken?